# Regularized hypergeometric function 1f2 for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any library in python 3.X that includes a good regularized hypergeometric function 1f2?

I tried using SciPy and mpmath however I could not find the reularized version of the function.

Below is the function I am trying to recreate, I'm strugggling

[image]

Here is my code for both SciPy and mpmaths as an example.

```
mpmath.hyp1f2(1,(1-n/2),(3/2-n/2),-np.power(x,2)/4)
sc.hyp1f2(1,[(1-n/2),(3/2-n/2)],-np.power(x,2)/4)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of dividing hyp2f1 by gamma function. No?

If this is what you want it is easy to define:

```
from scipy.special import hyp2f1, gamma 

def hyp2f1regularized(a, b, c, d):
    return hyp2f1(a, b, c, d) / gamma(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for regularized generalized hypergeometric functions in any module but it's straightforward to calculate regularized ones on-the-fly. Divide by the product of the gamma functions of each denominator parameter.